# Controle de tabs bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-3

tenho três tabs com bootstrap, a opção pra navegar pelas tabs com os botões voltar e próximo estão funcionando, conforme imagem a baixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para que seja ativado a próxima tab somente se todos os campos da primeira forem preenchidos, da mesma forma na segunda tab, e deixar por padrão as duas ultimas tabs como desabilitada quando a primeira estiver ativa?

Comment: pode percorre todos os inputs com jquery, $('.input-cliente').each();

Comment: Dá pra desabilitar o botão `Próximo`, e só habilitar quando todos os campos estiverem preenchidos. Daí você linka este botão na outra guia, e assim sucessivamente... E no link da tab (`Preferências do cliente` p.ex.) vc coloca "#" no `href`, que é pra não ir pra tab clicando ali.  Dá pra fazer com jQuery ou JavaScript puro... posta o código aí que deves conseguir a resposta que procuras rapidamente. Em tempo: tbm é possível só habilitar o link da tab quando os campos estiverem preenchidos.

Comment: O mais complicado acho que é se você quiser validar todos os campos, porque cada um vai ter as regras específicas, mas se por exemplo você quiser apenas saber se houve modificação em todos os campos, pode usar a função `change` ou `one` pra verificar se todos os campos foram alterados...